# Edit creditmemo template pdf

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, pdf, creditmemo

I need to edit the pdf creditmemo generated from backend with the print button. I don't find the template. What is the path?

Answer (score 0):

Magento **credit Memo pdf is generate** from class `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Creditmemo`.

it is use `magento zend pdf for created pdf`.

If you want to something then you  need do code at

```
Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Creditmemo

Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Items_Creditmemo_Default
Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Items_Creditmemo_Group
```

Answer (score -1):

Default magento create pdf for credit memo from below file, if you wants to make change then you need to override that file with some of your custom extension, because if you upgrade magento then your changes will be oveeride with new version,

vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Creditmemo.php

Hope this will help,

Comment: This is M2 path, not M1